# Wanted to understand how compareTo method works when there is no implmentation

Tags: compareto

Could you please help me understand how the below code works

```
  static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean less(T v, T w) {
        return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
    }
```

I could see that there is no implementation given for the compareTo method and it still works fine, could you please let me know how it works.

I wanted to understand how the natural ordering is done. where can i see the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

The method has defined a constraint on the type `T`. Any `T` will be extending the `Comparable` interface which contains the compareTo() method.

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean less(T v, T w) {
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}
```

Based on that contract, any object passed into this method as `v` and `w` has to implement the `compareTo()` method.

To verify that, you can try something like below where a compilation error is shown.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     less(new Object(), new Object());
}
```

Hope this helps you in understanding it better.